# Why these Py4JJavaError showString errors while joining Spark dataframes using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, left-join

I'm trying to join dataframes in Spark using pyspark. These two dataframes are pretty large (one of them is more than 5GB), and I keep getting the errors below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-d940918c3fe6> in <module>()
      1 train_holiday_oil_store_transaction_item_test_004 = train_holiday_oil_store_transaction_item_test_004.drop('type', 'locale', 'locale_name', 'description', 'transferred')
----> 2 train_holiday_oil_store_transaction_item_test_004.show()

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate)
    334         """
    335         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 336             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
    337         else:
    338             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate)))

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o873.showString.
: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenOuter(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doProduce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.produce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And here are my codes:

```
train_holiday_oil_store_transaction_item_test_004 = train_holiday_oil_store_transaction_item_test_004.join(stores_df, 'store_nbr', 'left_outer')
train_holiday_oil_store_transaction_item_test_004 = train_holiday_oil_store_transaction_item_test_004.drop('city', 'state', 'store_type', 'cluster')
train_holiday_oil_store_transaction_item_test_004.show()
```

What's going on? What is a solution?

I increased the partition to 500 so it would not be the problem.

I'm also wondering what are the typical ways to join large dataframes while using pyspark? Does anyone have this kind of experience?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also [ask]--what has googling given you?

Comment: If you read [ask] it tells you to summarize your research, please do so. (So "of course" is irrelevant. Also the fact is that most unclear/non-MCVE/poor  questions if they have googled have done so poorly.) Please edit clarifications into your question, not commentss. Still no [mcve], please do what it says. In particular--*Complete*-code, input, output & expected output. And here, what happens with smaller test input? Also please ask your final questions in a different question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in your error message, you will see that spark is calling  **BroadcastHashJoin**. Since the dataframe is large, sending it results in timeout.
Few solutions to this problem

1. Increase `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout`
2. Force spark to use ShuffleHashJoin by setting `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1`
3. Use the same partitioner on both dataframes. For example if you have two dataframe and you wish to join them based on id column. You should repartition them by id column

   `df1 = df1.repartiton("id")`
   `df2 = df2.repartition("id")`